Redirect inbound with PHP (no htaccess)
I migrated a forum website from a self-hosted server to a cloud-hosted solution and didn't plan on a URL change. The problem is, I had some htaccess rewrites in place that isn't compatible with the URLs on the new cloud-hosted site, and unfortunately, I do not have access to an htaccess file to fix it and currently my inbounds from Google, and others have fallen off a cliff
So I'm looking for a way to redirect using PHP or others if possible.
Original site URL (take note of the S in "forums'):
https://www.mywebsite.com/forums/canon/182027-firmware-c5550i.html
all my inbounds fail because The New site uses this URL format ('forum' is singular)
https://www.mywebsite.com/forum/technical-forums/copier-technical-discussion/canon-aa...
I can get to the correct page with:
https://www.mywebsite.com/showthread.php?t=182027
I can place PHP on a page at https://www.mywebsite.com/forums, is it possible to use PHP to rewrite any inbounds containing /forums/ to have that 6-digit number stripped out and have it rewritten to https://www.mywebsite.com/showthread.php?t=182027?
I'm a novice at this stuff, I haven't tried anything and I'm out of ideas.
